# Command-Z in Applescript for current active application

Tags: command, applescript

I'm trying to make an undo function on AppleScript for the current active application.

My code actually works on the automator itself when I run it, but it doesn't when I launch it as a service via shortcut.

```
on run {input, parameters}
    tell application "System Events" to keystroke "z"
end run
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to send the keystroke using {command down}

```
tell application "System Events" to keystroke "z" using {command down}
```

Also, I don't think a service will accomplish what you are trying to do. A background application which is called through spotlight would probably work better. However, the work of calling any solution seems to be as much if not more than simply typing command z manually.